# Qlikview: Total of calculated metric based on calculated dimension

Tags: qlikview

I started working on Qlikview a week back and I am working on this dashboard.

I have a particular requirement which I am not able to achieve:

So, I have a calculated dimension "Categories" added in my script which based on certain conditions tags each name as SLEEPERS,STARS,WEAKLINKS etc.

Now, I have flagged the names based on certain condition which works fine.

The issue is, I want the sum of those flags on the level of calculated dimension CATEGORIES(SLEEPERS, STARS..etc) and my month field.

I am not able to achieve it because, the flag itself is a calculated field so sum of calculated field doesn't work. I tried using aggr, function but it returns zero for all rows. I am not sure why. in the aggr function I use the sum(Aggr(Flag,MONTH,Categories))

Can someone suggest a work around for this? I have attached the screenshot of the report for better understanding of the requirement

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want, can you provide more code and the screenshot that is missing?

Comment: What data is contained in the `Flag` field? Are you doing this all in the script, or is the calculation occurring in a chart expression?